# Candidate has non-matching type UITableView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, swift

Xcode says that "Candidate has non-matching type UITableView....."Anyone know how to figure this out?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) 
-> Int {
        return dataSource[section].count
       }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) 
-> UITableViewCell? {
        let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)                   as             UITableViewCell

        if let path = indexPath{
            let currentString = dataSource[path.section][path.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = currentString
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.Little more explanation of the scenario might help out the experts to understand the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function signatures have changed. You need to update to these:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)  -> Int {
```

and

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

Comment: Thanks! The first one works now, but an error appears on "if let path = indexPath" after I delete the "!", and says "bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type". What should I do?

Comment: Since indexPath is no longer optional, you don't need the `if` condition. Try remove that.