# UITableView not showing custom tableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

i've created  a customTableViewCell with the identifier SwitchViewCell which i would like to show in a UITableView. The problem is that it does not show. How come the first cell does not contain the SwitchViewCell?

## Delegates

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate
```

## tableView

```
    var tableView = UITableView(frame:CGRectMake(0, profileImageView.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - profileImageView.frame.size.height), style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "SwitchViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SwitchViewCell")
    tableView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
```

## Delegate Methods

```
func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SwitchViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SwitchViewCell

        cell.cellLabel?.text = "lol"

        return cell
    }

    return nil
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView?) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    return 44;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever set the controller as the data source?

Comment: When i add UITableViewDataSource it gives me following error: type 'ProfileViewController' does not conform protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

Comment: @PeterPik I have answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25802735/58129